# How to save [[Bool]] in Swift (Encode for archive array of Boolean arrays)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, archive, nscoding

I am having no difficulty archiving Int, String, Bool and Date but archiving an array of Boolean arrays is not working, here is a portion of the code:

```
class PlayerInfo: NSObject, NSCoding
{
    public var score: Int = 0
    public var lastPlayed: Date = Date()
    public var visited: [[Bool]] = []
    public var ringFound: Bool = false

    init(dictionary: [String : AnyObject])
    {
        score = dictionary[ArchiveKeys.Score] as! Int
        lastPlayed = dictionary[ArchiveKeys.LastPlayed] as! Date
        visited = dictionary[ArchiveKeys.Visited] as! [[Bool]]        
        ringFound = dictionary[ArchiveKeys.RingFound] as! Bool
    }

    func encode(with archiver: NSCoder)
    {
        archiver.encode(score, forKey: ArchiveKeys.Score)
        archiver.encode(lastPlayed, forKey: ArchiveKeys.LastPlayed)
        archiver.encode(visited, forKey: ArchiveKeys.Visited)
        archiver.encode(ringFound, forKey: ArchiveKeys.RingFound)
    }

    required init(coder unarchiver: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init()
        score = unarchiver.decodeInteger(forKey: ArchiveKeys.Score)
        lastPlayed = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: ArchiveKeys.LastPlayed) as! Date
        visited = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: ArchiveKeys.Visited) as! [[Bool]]
        ringFound = unarchiver.decodeBool(forKey: ArchiveKeys.RingFound)
    }

    class func retrieveCurrentGame() -> PlayerInfo!
    {
        let filePath: String = retrievePreviousGameFilePath(fileName: currentGameName)

        if let game = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: filePath) as? PlayerInfo
        {
            print("retrieving previous game - found a game for previous day")
            return game
        }
        else
        {
            print("retrieving previous game - can't find game data")
            return nil
        }
    }

    class func retrievePreviousGameFilePath(fileName: String) -> String
    {
        let kFileNameExtension: String = ".game"

        let fileNameWithExtension: String = fileName + kFileNameExtension
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let url = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first! as NSURL
        print("url= " + (url.appendingPathComponent(fileNameWithExtension)?.path)!)
        return (url.appendingPathComponent(fileNameWithExtension)?.path)!

    }

    public func saveCurrentGame()
    {
        let fileName: String = currentGameName + ".game"
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let url = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first! as NSURL
        print("url= " + (url.appendingPathComponent(fileName)?.path)!)
        let filePath: String = (url.appendingPathComponent(fileName)?.path)!
        NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(self, toFile: filePath)
    }    

}
```

I am unable to retrieve the [[Bool]] visited with my code. Is there a better way to encode?

FOLLOWUP FOR werm098:

I revised the encoding to:

```
        let visitedData: Data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: visited)
        archiver.encode(visitedData, forKey: ArchiveKeys.Visited)
//        archiver.encode(visited, forKey: ArchiveKeys.Visited)
```

and decoding to:

```
        let visitedData: Data = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: ArchiveKeys.Visited) as! Data
        visited = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: visitedData) as! [[Bool]]
//        visited = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: ArchiveKeys.Visited) as! [[Bool]]
```

But this still does not work?

Any other ideas?

Comment: Unable how? What happens instead? Error message, etc?

Comment: I put this code in a playground and was able to reproduce the same strange behavior. Currently I am unable to fully investigate the issue but my suggestion is to try converting the object to NSData first then save the data and later retrieve the data with `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data)`

Comment: No error, just no data.

Comment: werm098:  I tried your suggestion but it is not working, see code above. Any other thoughts on how to go about saving a [[Bool]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that simple example is pretty much a working solution for `[[Bool]]`, you may take a look on that and check it how that works.

```
class MyClass: NSObject, NSCoding {

    public var boolArray: [[Bool]]? = nil

    // MARK: Init

    override init() {
        self.boolArray = [[true, false, false], [false, true, false], [true, true, false]] // or any random sequece...
        debugPrint("It was inited.")
    }

    // MARK: - Archiving / Unarchiving

    func archived() -> Data {
        return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self)
    }

    class func unarchived(fromData data: Data) -> MyClass? {
        return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? MyClass
    }

    // MARK: - <NSCoding>

    private enum Key {
        case boolArray
    }

    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(self.boolArray, forKey: String(describing: Key.boolArray))
        debugPrint("It was encoded.")
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.boolArray = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: String(describing: Key.boolArray)) as? [[Bool]]
        debugPrint("It was decoded.")
    }

}
```

---

and it is time to test it:

```
let myClass = MyClass()
debugPrint(myClass.boolArray)

let archivedData: Data = myClass.archived()
// do something with the data here... e.g. permanent storing
// ...

// ...
// restore back the data here from e.g. background storage device
let unarchivedObject: MyClass = MyClass.unarchived(fromData: archivedData)

debugPrint(unarchivedObject.boolArray)
```

---

and the console should look like:

```
"It was inited"
Optional([[true, false, false], [false, true, false], [true, true, false]])
"It was encoded."
"It was decoded."
Optional([[true, false, false], [false, true, false], [true, true, false]])
```

which means after unarchiving you can get back your values in one piece.

Comment: It was working, just not reading it correctly on restart of app. Thank you.